# using Adsense API, How can I find which application an admob ad unit id belongs to?

Tags: google-api, admob, adsense, adsense-api

Adsense api returns ad unit names associated with the ad unit id. But the names aren't unique like "on main page". These adunits are part of an application created using admob. Some applications have more than 1 ad unit. I can't seem to find an api call that will tell me the application name an ad unit id belongs to. How can I get the application name of a adunit id using their API?

Comment: Exactly what method are you calling and what is it's signature. You can name your AdUnits whatever you like if you have access to them, which presumably you do.

Comment: I'm using this api call: adsense.accounts.reports.generate with dimension AD_UNIT_ID & name. I don't see an "Application" dimension in there docs. I prefer not to change the adunits names as there are alot of them (more than 100). I did a hack which is get all ad units for a week, then do the same on the admob web interface. export it and try to match them up based on similar stats. Which worked reasonably well but not perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Update: Admob Now have a Dimension for App Name

Use this dimension: `APP_NAME` in the Advanced Reporting

Source: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/reporting

Here is an example of getting the app name:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/adsense/v1.4/accounts/{{You account Id}}/reports?startDate=today&endDate=today&metric=EARNINGS&key={{YOUR API KEY}}&dimension=AD_UNIT_ID&dimension=AD_UNIT_NAME&dimension=APP_NAME
```

Now copy your App name, and add it inside filter, e.g. `filter=APP_NAME%3D={{Your App Name}}` to exclude other apps. Here is a complete example:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/adsense/v1.4/accounts/{{You account Id}}/reports?startDate=today&endDate=today&metric=EARNINGS&key={{YOUR API KEY}}&filter=APP_NAME%3D={{Your App Name}}&dimension=AD_UNIT_ID&dimension=AD_UNIT_NAME&dimension=APP_NAME
```

Answer (score 3):

As far I know, your-own ad unit "name convention" (like app001_abc, app002_def, app003_ghi) and "Contains substring" filters like `AD_UNIT_NAME=@app001_`, `AD_UNIT_NAME=@app002_`, `AD_UNIT_NAME=@app003_` is probably the only option. (In v1.4.)

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/adsense/v1.4/accounts/pub-0123456789012345/reports?startDate=today&endDate=today&dimension=AD_UNIT_ID&dimension=AD_UNIT_NAME&filter=AD_UNIT_NAME%3D%40app001_&metric=EARNINGS&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/reporting/filtering
https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.4/reference/accounts/adunits#resource

Comment: This is the best answer so far though not perfect, and perhaps adsense api doesn't have the functionality I need. I'm marking this as the answer until something better comes up.

Answer (score 1):

> There's currently no dimension for apps

Writing from the year 2017. Now you can use APP_ID / APP_NAME / APP_PLATFORM as filters or dimensions in reports. Combining APP_ID with AD_UNIT_ID you can separate ad units in report by appropriate apps.

Example:

```
'dimension' => ['DATE','AD_UNIT_ID'],
'filter' => 'APP_ID==2:com.my.app'
```

Prefix 1 is for iOS, 2 - for Android. You can also use numeric APP_ID - from [App management](https://apps.admob.com/#account/appmgmt:) page

More examples are in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/reporting)

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no dimension for apps. You can group the AdMob requests if you add `AD_CLIENT_ID` to the list of dimensions of your report, or filter them.

The ad units created with AdSense (for content) have ad client IDs similar to `"ca-pub-1234567890"` and the ones created with AdMob are different, like `"ca-app-pub-1234567890"`.

Comment: you're referring to the AD_UNIT_ID not AD_CLIENT_ID. Adsense's api allows for filtering specifically admob id's.

Comment: An ad client is not an account. It's an association between product (AFC, AFS, AdMob...) and an account. So first do accounts.adclients.list and then filter by AD_CLIENT_ID. You can try it here:
https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.4/reference/accounts/adclients/list

Comment: Sorry, I thought you just wanted to tell them apart, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: you're right AD_CLIENT_ID is for a specific product. Strangely I have more than a few products to deal with and they all have the same AD_CLIENT_ID. I have to filter them for a specific product using PRODUCT_CODE dimension. Galeksic is more on track on what I want to do. My goal is to get the application name that the AD_UNIT_ID belongs to. Check if an AD_UNIT_ID belongs to the admob product is very straight forward to do, and is not my end goal.